# Cocos2d: ARC releasing CCSprite too soon?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I enabled ARC for my cocos2d project.

Now i try doing the following:

```
   BuildTowerMenu *menu = [BuildTowerMenu menuAtLocation:tileScreenPos];

   [self addChild:menu];
```

And in the BuildTowerMenu class:

```
+(id)menuAtLocation:(CGPoint)location {
   return [[self alloc] initMenuAt:location];
}

-(id) initMenuAt:(CGPoint)location {
    if (self = [super init]) {
      self.position = location;
      CCSprite *item1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
      item1.position = location;

      [self addChild:item1];
    }
    return self;
}
```

But for some reason, the Sprite never shows up. After a bit of debugging i see that when i return from menuAtLocation, the CCSprite is still in the Array of children of BuildTowerMenu, but empty (only got an id).

If i actually add the sprite from outside it works and the Sprite is displayed:

```
BuildTowerMenu *menu = [BuildTowerMenu menuAtLocation:tileScreenPos];

CCSprite *item1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
item1.position = location;
[menu addChild:item1];

[self addChild:menu];
```

Any hints on what i did wrong here?

P.S.: i added a breakpoint in the dealloc of CCSprite, which never gets called (i guess it should be called if ARC is releasing it)...

Comment: Ok, it had nothing to do with ARC; the Sprite which seemed to be released was there, it was just a debugger - bug which didnt display it correctly.
The problem was actually the line

    self.position = location;

After moving the setposition after the addChild, everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented on the initial question_:
Ok, it had nothing to do with ARC; the Sprite which seemed to be released was there, it was just a debugger - bug which didnt display it correctly. The problem was actually the line self.position = location; After moving the setposition after the addChild, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you set equal positions to your menu and sprite. 
I mean that this part of code

```
CGPoint location = ccp(200.f, 200.f);
[menu setPosition: location];
[sprite setPosition: location];
[menu addChild: sprite];
```

will add your sprite with position position (400.f, 400.f), relatieve to the menu's parent. You are doing almost the same thing in your BuildTowerMenu's `initMenuAt:` method/